# How to ensure Gerrit displays differences for reviewers compared to the original source code instead of the last commit?

Tags: gerrit

As I developed a new feature for my job, I committed the code multiple times to the main branch. Now, I need to push the code to Gerrit for my manager's review. However, after pushing the code, all the commits I made are bundled and pushed together. As a result, when my manager reviews the code of the last commit (which is the only commit needed to be reviewed), Gerrit displays code differences compared to the previous commit instead of the original source code. To avoid this, I was advised to use the --amend option when committing. Though this option works, it merges all the commits into a single commit, which means I won't be able to go back to a specific commit, If I ever need. Therefore, I'm looking for a simple way to let my manager review the latest commit on Gerrit with a comparison to the original source code (before any commit was made) while also having the flexibility to make multiple commits during the development process.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** you can't do that.

**Long answer:**

Gerrit is a code review tool that helps teams collaborate on code changes. The idea behind Gerrit is to make it easier for reviewers to understand the changes being made and to provide feedback on those changes.

One way Gerrit does this is by encouraging atomic commits. An atomic commit is a single, self-contained change that can be easily reviewed and understood by others. By making atomic commits, developers can more easily see what has changed in the codebase and understand the context of those changes.

The developer breaks down a change into atomic commits before the submission for review in Gerrit. This makes it easier for reviewers to understand the changes being made and provide feedback on those changes. Reviewers can comment on individual commits, providing feedback on specific changes, rather than having to review the entire change all at once.

In summary, Gerrit promotes atomic commits to facilitate the review process, allowing for more efficient and effective collaboration on code changes.